# How to debug react-native-web through expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

So I launched the standard task `expo start --web`

It serves the bundle well, but when it comes to debugger I can't find any sourcemap to put my breakpoints on. There is just the bundle.
I use the browser debugger

[image: no sourcemap ?]

Another debugger question on android this time `expo start --android`

Everything starts well, I launch the debugger through expo terminal. It launches but the code is not stopping at any breakpoint.

Let me know if any idea, thanks in advance